# Powerhell Select-Object not showing all attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get a list of certain attributes on users.
Some attributes are not displayed however.

Code:

```
Get-ADUser -identity THEUSERNAME| Select-Object Surname, GivenName, SamAccountName, physicaldeliveryofficename
```

With this code I get `Surname`, `Givenname`, `SamAccountname` but not the `physicaldeliveryofficename`.

How can I get these special extra attributes to display in the output?

Comment: Because that's the way [it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps): "This cmdlet returns a default set of ADUser property values. To retrieve additional ADUser properties, use the Properties parameter."

Answer (score 0):

As @VonPryz mentions in the comments, that's the way the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet works.

Take a look at [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-3-get-all-of-the-properties-for-a-specified-user) from the microsoft documentation where they specify that all properties should be fetched.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity ChewDavid -Properties *
```

Output:

```
Surname           : David
Name              : Chew David
UserPrincipalName :
GivenName         : David
Enabled           : False
SamAccountName    : ChewDavid
ObjectClass       : user
SID               : S-1-5-21-2889043008-4136710315-2444824263-3544
ObjectGUID        : e1418d64-096c-4cb0-b903-ebb66562d99d
DistinguishedName : CN=Chew David,OU=NorthAmerica,OU=Sales,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM
```